# Is there a PHP CMS which requires you to use UPPERCASE db column names?

Tags: php, content-management-system

I am converting a medium sized site from an unknown cms, I got to look at a dump of the tables (all 9 of them) and was struck by, amongst other things, all of the column names being uppercase.  Anyone know of a PHP CMS which enforces this behaviour?

Comment: Do you want to find out which CMS was used? In that case, posting the table names would probably be more helpful

Comment: Is the site live somewhere now? I assume  you dont have access to the source, but the HTML output might hold some clues.

Answer (score 0):

Post the table names and look for a table called configuration or similar. Do you have the CMS's source code or at least directory structure?